# Create new attachments Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, email-attachments, cdo.message, vba

does anyone know how to remove an attachment object from VBA? i'm trying to do an application in Excel using VBA such it will will send emails depending on the data found on the excel file. In my code below, the emails are sent, however, the last email has all the attachments from the previous ones. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnSendEmail_Click()
For Counter = 2 To 3
    Dim Mail As New Message
    Dim Config As New Configuration
    Set Config = Mail.Configuration
    Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 465
    Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
    Config(cdoSendUserName) = "test@gmail.com"
    Config(cdoSendPassword) = "test"
    Config.Fields.Update
    Set curFirstName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 1)
    Set curLastName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2)
    Set curEmail = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 3)
    Set curAttach = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 4)
    Mail.To = curEmail.Value
    Mail.From = Config(cdoSendUserName)
    Mail.Subject = "This is a test!"
    Mail.HTMLBody = "<h1>" & curFirstName.Value & " " & curLastName.Value & "</h1>"
    Mail.AddAttachment curAttach.Value
    Mail.Send
Next Counter
MsgBox "Sent"
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are using early-binding and therefore have a reference to `Microsoft Outlook xx.0 Object Library`. If that's the case you should have auto-complete in the VBE and should be able to see the various options for `Mail.` including `Mail.Attachments.Remove`. If you are using another library for early-binding then please include it in your post.

Comment: @Ralph, i'm using "Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library". Should i be using any other reference?

Comment: No, `CDO` is fine. Just include it the next time in your post. I changed your post to include the appropriate *flag*. Anyway, with `CDO` you can use the following line to remove all attachments: `Mail.Attachments.DeleteAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code should work:

```
Mail.Attachments.DeleteAll
```